# Does Ignite on YARN support Node Labels?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, ignite

I know Ignite still does not support setting up custom YARN queues from this JIRA ticket - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2738 . I cannot find any information on whether Ignite supports running its containers within specified YARN node labels?

Currently in our cluster we have labelled all of our nodes and in attempting to start an Ignite applicaiton, the app is stuck in **Pending stage because it is waiting for resources to be assigned from AM, with the AM container Node Label expression defaulting to `<DEFAULT_PARTITION>` .**

Is there a way to supply node labels for Ignite on YARN?

Answer (score 0):

`ignite-yarn` doesn't seem to set node labels.

Have you tried specifying them externally?